# How do I print a set of numbers and the sum of the squares from 1 to each number from the list?

Tags: java

How do I code this question in two different methods? I know this can be done within a loop and a nested loop but it needs to be done this way. I'm aware it's all wrong, but I need help understanding the logic.

```
    public static int numloop(int n){
        int nd = 0;
        for(n = 5; n <= 49; n += 2){
            nd = ndiv(n);
        }
      return nd;
    }
    public static int ndiv(int numb){    
        int sumsq = 0; 
        for( int x = 1; x <= numb; x++ ){
            sumsq += x * x;

        }  
     return sumsq;   
    }
     public static void main(String[]args){

       System.out.println("NUMBER\t" + "SUMSQ");
       System.out.println(n + nd);
    }
```

The output should look like something like this:

Number ||  Sum of square

5   ||  55

7  || 140

9 || 285

Comment: Can you give a sample expected output?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple @Tony. If you want this to be done using 2 methods, then just split it up as follows:

- One method to just take the input number as parameter and calculate
  sum of squares(squares found in another method)
- Another method to calculate the squares of the numbers.

So here is the overview of the flow of the program:

1. Accept the number
2. pass the number into the 1st method mentioned above
3. In the 1st method, loop from 1 to the number.. call the `Square()` method for each `i` value. calculate the sum simultaneously;
4. Print the sum once all iterations are done..

I have attached the code and its output below:

**CODE:**

```
import java.io.*;

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader ip = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ip);
    int c = 1;
    do {
      System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
      int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      squaresum(n);
      System.out.println("\nPress 1 to continue, 0 to stop..");
      c = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }while(c == 1);
    System.out.println("Stopped.");
  }

  public static void squaresum(int num) {
    int n = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
      n += square(i);
    System.out.println("Sum is: " + n);
  }

  public static int square(int n) {
    return (n*n);
  }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Enter a number:
>
> 5
>
> Sum is: 55
>
> Press 1 to continue, 0 to stop..
>
> 1
>
> Enter a number:
>
> 9
>
> Sum is: 285
>
> Press 1 to continue, 0 to stop..
>
> 0
>
> Stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Tony - could not work out exactly for the code exactly you wanted so I took the liberty of making it a little more flexible. It should be easy for you to restrict it to do only what you want.

```
public class SumSquare {

    public static int numloop(int start, int end, int increment){
        int nd = 0;
        for(int i = start; i <= end; i += increment){
            nd = ndiv(i);
            System.out.println(i + " || " + nd);
        }
      return nd;
    }
    public static int ndiv(int numb){    
        int sumsq = 0; 
        for( int x = 1; x <= numb; x++ ){
            sumsq += x * x;

        }  
     return sumsq;   
    }
     public static void main(String[]args){
       System.out.println("Number" + " || " + "Sum of square");
       numloop(5, 49, 2);
    }    
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
run:
Number || Sum of square
5 || 55
7 || 140
9 || 285
11 || 506
13 || 819
15 || 1240
17 || 1785
19 || 2470
21 || 3311
23 || 4324
25 || 5525
27 || 6930
29 || 8555
31 || 10416
33 || 12529
35 || 14910
37 || 17575
39 || 20540
41 || 23821
43 || 27434
45 || 31395
47 || 35720
49 || 40425
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```